# Integrating trignometric finctions with exponetial arguments

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I want to integrate a trigonometric function where the argument contains an exponential function.
$$f(t) = \cos\left(\omega_{0} \left(1 - e^{-t/\tau} \right) t \right)$$
where $\omega_{0}$, $\tau$, and $t$ are all real and positive. The end game is to use this in Fourier Transforms.

Does anyone know any integral identities, or integration tricks to perform this? I have tried using a series expansion of $e^{x} =\sum1 + x^{n}/n! $ to a fixed number of $n$ to approximate but this doesn't help either.

---

So what in the end I want to achieve is the following,
$$\int_{0}^{T} \cos\left(\omega_{0} \left(1 - e^{-t/\tau} \right) t \right) \ dt $$
and then finally if I can,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \cos\left(\omega_{0} \left(1 - e^{-t/\tau} \right) t \right) e^{i \omega t}\ dt $$

Comment: [It seems like there is no nice looking anti-derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos(a*x*(1-e%5E(-x%2Fn))))

Comment: So I have already tried things like Mathematica and Numerically integrating gives a hard number if I set a hard limit.

Comment: What is a *"hard number"* and a *"hard limit"*? Could you include these within your post instead of in the comment section?

Comment: Sure, so if I say integrate from $0$ to ideally $\infty$, or $T$, where $T$ is some real, positive number then it can be numerically integrated. But that just gives a number. I really need a function in $t$ because I want to FT this function.

Comment: @mrtaurho done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Long story short: there exists no expression in terms of known mathematical functions as [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos(omega*t*(1-e%5E(-t%2Ftau)))) returns. However, we will walk through several simplifications aswell as reshapings to show *why* it is so hard, i.e. impossible with the current functions avaible, to find a closed-form anti-derivative.

One of the main problems we have to face is the quite unusual argument of the cosine function. For the sake of simplicity we will omit the role of the two occuring constants by letting $\omega_0=\tau=1$ $($note, the crucial point of what follows is not affected by this decision$)$. Now apply the difference formula of the cosine function to get

$$\cos\left(\omega_0t(1-e^{-t/\tau})\right)\stackrel{\omega_0=\tau=1}\mapsto\cos\left(t(1-e^{-t})\right)=\cos(t)\cos(te^{-t})+\sin(t)\sin(te^{-t})$$

We will now focus on the first summand hence a similiar strategy can be exploited for the second summand too. Recall Euler's Formula to rewrite the cosine in terms of complex exponentials. We are left with terms of the form

$$\large e^{it(1+e^{-t})},~e^{it(1-e^{-t})},~e^{-it(1+e^{-t})},~e^{-it(1-e^{-t})}$$

Essentially these different exponentials are of the form "$x^{-x}$" $($apply the substitution $e^{-t}\mapsto t$ to see what I am refering to$)$. This function, however, is an example of functions for those we *cannot* find an anti-derivative in terms of elementary functions. Eventually this is the reason *why* it is hardly possible to find a closed-form anti-derivative of your given function. Nevertheless, it might be of help to actually perform the aforementioned substitution and expand the exponential as a series afterwards which would be similiar to the proof of the so-called [Sophomores's Dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) in order to obtain a reasonable approximation.

Concerning your end game of finding the Fourier Transform of this function: adding the factor of $e^{i\omega t}$ does not alter the complicated inherent structure of the integrand from which it might be concluded that there is no expression in terms of known functions aswell $($in fact, [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+Transform+cos(omega*t*(1-e%5E(-t%2Ftau)))) fails again to find a suitable expression$)$. Even though it might be easier to exploit numerical methods here since we are dealing with a definite integral rather than an indefinite.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had a hunch that there probably wasn't a analytical solution and you're answer has really succinctly explained it. I think the best approach I can take is the Fourier Transform of a constant frequency -- yielding some kind of Lorentzian peak and then convolving other functions into this.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin Glad to help! :)